# How to detect when user's finger away the element?

Tags: javascript, ipad, touch

Now user taps the image, moves the finger away, release finger and can see the alert. 
Is it possible to check where user release finger and if he still on original image to show him alert? Otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Are you using UIGestures or is this a UIButton subclass of some kind? Can you show us the code you're already using.

Comment: I assume he's using JavaScript because of the tag. @Castro Is that correct?

Comment: Oh didn't notice. I have iPad as a favorite tag and just assumed it was programming for an app. Good luck with your website haha.

Comment: Yes, I using jquery/javascript. This is HTML content in uiwebview

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var touchedObject;

$('body').bind("touchstart", function(e){
    touchedObject = $(this);
});

$('body').bind("touchend", function(e){
    if (touchedObject == $(this)) {
        //show alert
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it can help. I think possible to check is the object where touch start fired is  the same as the object where fired touchend event without using coordinates or sizes. But I don't know how.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunatelly, alert in touchend évent function listener is never fired